# JBOSS don't display image in hard drive

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ubuntu-14.04

I'm developing a Java EE  app under Ubuntu and using JBOSS.

I'm uploading image to folder /opt/files/ and it work fine.

My problem is that i cannot display the image, cause i don't know how to access it cause the default URL start by localhost:8080/app/...

So how can i access an image in hard drive.

Thanks for helping me guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo must write a Servlet for this purpose. The full code in: http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-servlet-download-file-example

```
package net.codejava;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class DownloadFileServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // reads input file from an absolute path
        String filePath = "E:/Test/Download/MYPIC.JPG";
        File downloadFile = new File(filePath);
        FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);

        // if you want to use a relative path to context root:
        String relativePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("");
        System.out.println("relativePath = " + relativePath);

        // obtains ServletContext
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();

        // gets MIME type of the file
        String mimeType = context.getMimeType(filePath);
        if (mimeType == null) {        
            // set to binary type if MIME mapping not found
            mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
        }
        System.out.println("MIME type: " + mimeType);

        // modifies response
        response.setContentType(mimeType);
        response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());

        // forces download
        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", downloadFile.getName());
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

        // obtains response's output stream
        OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;

        while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        inStream.close();
        outStream.close();     
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you,this definitely helped me.